# how to cherry pick commits while push to the same branch

Tags: github, git-commit, git-push, git

I have following commit ids in git log against my some feature branch.(feature/navigation)

```
git log --pretty=oneline

8fc7aeb 
7b7809e
20d9bb2
7f302cb
9f0a3b5
fad0df5
011886a
```

If it was one commit the following command will do.

```
git push origin 7b7809e:feature/navigation
```

But here I am in need to push 4 commits which are not in order.

the commits that I need to pick from the above list are:-

#1 8fc7aeb 
 #2 7b7809e 
 #4 7f302cb 
 #6 fad0df5

How can I do this?? (Pushing commits on the same branch i.e., feature/navigation)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution would be to rename current branch to something
else, for example:

```
git branch -m feature/navigation feature/navigation.bak
```

Then re-create a new branch called `feature/navigation` from your
stable branch, then manually cherry-pick commits from
`feature/navigation.bak` you are interested in and push
`feature/navigation` normally:

```
git push -u origin feature/navigation
```

Creating branches in git is very cheap.

Comment: make sense!! let's see if any better approach pops up..Thanks!!

Comment: really good solution